# Sharphound / Bloodhound full enumeration

Tags: active-directory

I am working with Sharphound / Bloodhound tools to create a "map" of my active directory domain. It works fine.

I have now a complex environment. There are multiple domains/forests. There is trust between them.

Is there a way to ask Sharphound to collect absolutely ALL data for all domains?

I need to run Sharphound for each domain and I would like to automate this. Is there a way to do that?